# AC compressor stopped working, electrical/program issue

Tags: ac, computer, compressor, program

My Ac was working fine untill 2 days ago, I was accelrating normally and then generic error messege appeared on the dash and the AC stopped! (fans and compressor).

I tested the fans, they are woking fine then tried a trick the other day. I disconnected the bettery for about 5 minutes and reconnected. Everything worked fine. I tried many times switching the AC on and off and it worked perfectly. But when I tried to move the car and made a sudden accelration while driving, the same thing happened! Compressor does not respond!.

Today I checked the AC gas, the compressor wiring. Everything is fine. 
Sent the car to a workshop here, they tested the AC fuses and I'm waiting their final diagnosis tonight.

If anybody had any clue what is that because -in fact- i don't trust local service shops around here and they may overdo.

[Chevy Lumina '06 3.6 V6]

Answer (score 1):

ECUs are generally supposed to disengage the clutch of a clutch equipped AC compressor when WOT is reached. Something is there to check if the engine is in WOT condition, it may be faulty and be temporarily reset each time battery power is removed, try looking for any switches in the gas pedal assembly or having a thorough OBD check done with an OBD scanner advanced enough to record live data.